# Move Column to the Left

Tags: vba, excel

Hey guys I just had a quick question about moving a column to the left using VBA. I am moving column 25 to A1 and this works fine, but it is replacing the column 1. How do I rewrite this code, so that the column I'm moving does not replace the column that I am moving it to? Thank you.

This is the code I have so far. I want basically every column from A1 to move right, so that nothing is deleted except the column that I am moving.

```
Sub Move_Column_Left()

    Columns(25).Cut Range("A1")

    Columns(25).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Columns(25).Cut
Columns(1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```